# Change a function, found inside a plugin's class in thrive visual editor

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am using the Thrive visual editor, for the "Post grid" element, when you go inside the grid options, there is a field there that says "Individual Posts / Pages" which it only pulls post/pages and my custom post type is not being pulled

Here is the code found inside "class-tcb-postgrid-element.php"

```
class TCB_Postgrid_Element extends TCB_Element_Abstract {

    /**
     * Constructs the post lists for "Individual Post / Pages filter"
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function get_posts_list( $term ) {
        $args    = array(
            'order_by'    => 'post_title',
            'post_type'   => array( 'page', 'post' ),
            'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
            's'           => $term,
        );
        $results = new WP_Query( $args );

        $list = array();
        foreach ( $results->get_posts() as $post ) {
            $list[] = array( 'id' => $post->ID, 'text' => $post->post_title );
        }

        return $list;
    }

    //... other functions here

}
```

as you can see if I add a post type it works but I am editing the plugin file itself

```
'post_type'   => array( 'page', 'post', 'application', 'services' ),
```

How can I modify this so that I can add it in my functions.php file?

Comment: You can't. If the plugin doesn't expose an action or a filter, you can't modify it from outside. And redefining the class outside of the plugin would throw a fatal error, since the definition would exist twice.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, there is not. You can make your own copy of the plugin and make whatever changes you want there, but logically you'll lose the ability to update safely.